# MongooseError: document must have an _id before saving at new MongooseError

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a registration page that takes input username and password to store into a mongoDB. [image: registration screen]

When I click on the Register button, it loads an error page.
 [image: register error]

Which also causes a Mongoose Error in the terminal that says MongooseError: document must have an _id before saving at new MongooseError

[image]

Below are the code.

```js
//server.js file
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var port = 8888;
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

/*Body parser*/
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

/*Database connection - MongoDB*/

//Created from the command earlier. Ensure this is done on the first_db instance
var username = 'admin';
var password = '123456';

var dbHost = 'localhost';
var dbPort = '27017';
var database = 'first_db';

var url = 'mongodb://' + username + ':' + password + '@' + dbHost + ':' + dbPort + '/' + database;
console.log('mongodb connection = ' + url);

mongoose.connect(url, function(err) {
    if(err) {
        console.log('connection error: ', err);
    } else {
        console.log('connection successful');
    }
});


/***********
Declare all models here
***********/

//User model
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
     _id: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
     username: String,
     password: String
 });

var User = mongoose.model('user', UserSchema);


/***********
All routes go below
***********/



app.get('/', function (req, res, next){
 res.sendFile( __dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.get('/register', function (req, res, next) {
    res.sendFile( __dirname + '/register.html');
});

app.post('/register', function (req, res, next) {
    User.create(req.body, function(err, saved) {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.json({ message : err });
    } else {
        res.json({ message : "User successfully registered!"});
    }
 });
});

app.listen(port, '0.0.0.0', function(){
 console.log('Server running at port ' + port);
});
```

```html
//register.html file
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My first NodeJS Website</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Registration page</p>

        <form action="/register" method="post">
            <p>Username <input type="text" name="username" /></p>
            <p>Password <input type="password" name="password" /></p>
            <input type="submit" value="Register"/>
        </form>

        <p><a href="/">Click here to go back.</a> </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

```html
//index.html file
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My first NodeJS Website</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Hello World!</p>

        <form action="/login" method="post">
            <p>Username <input type="text" name="username" /></p>
            <p>Password <input type="password" name="password" /></p>
            <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
        </form>

        <p>Not yet registered? <a href="/register">Click here to create an account.</a> </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't have to define the `_id` as `mongoose.Schema.ObjectId` in the `User` schema. MongoDB will implicitly generate the ID even if you don't define it in the schema and insert your object even if you don't provide value for `_id`. However, if you define it explicitly in the schema, Mongoose runs a validation check and expects you to provide the value - it will throw an error and your query won't even reach the database.